# SQL Server stored procedure with uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have written this to filter a view with uniqueidentifier GUID :

```
Alter PROCEDURE popclinom(@ixliente nvarchar(60))
as
   select 
      idcliente, nome, endere, Tel, celular, cidade, cpf, iest  
   from 
      Vw_RegCliente 
   where 
      idcliente like cast(@ixcliente as uniqueidentifier)
```

but this code returns

> Must declare the scalar variable "@ixcliente".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing  a "c" in your variable: `@ixliente` <> `@ixcliente`

Answer (score 2):

You have made syntax mistake:

ix***c***liente instead of `ixliente`